# Kernel module in D

Tags: linux-kernel, d, kernel-module

Is it possible to create a kernel module in D?

I’d like to write a device driver for Arch, using [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html). I’m having trouble finding info on this, perhaps by someone who’s been down this path already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing [Kernel module in D in google](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Kernel+module+in+D) gives me 4th result with [Proof of Concept: Writing a Linux Kernel Module in D](https://iainbuclaw.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-in-d/).
Yes, it's possible to create a kernel module using D.